# Generate Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have generated an excel (.xls) document using Apache POI. I use HSSF classes.

Could someone advise me on the following question:

*How can we keep the column headers in the diaplay part constant and have scroll only on the data part?*

That is, I want the header columns to be always visible when the excel file is scrolled down.

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 4):

One option may be the repeating rows suggestion from timboo. Not sure on your exact needs, but it's possible you might want a Freeze Pane instead.

To have the first row always on screen, never scrolling off, you'd do:

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("No Scroll");
sheet1.createFreezepane(0,1);
```

You can freeze rows, columns or both, see [this javadoc](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createFreezePane%28int,%20int%29) or [this](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html#createFreezePane%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29) for details

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [Apache POI Busy Developers Guide:](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Repeating)

> It's possible to set up repeating rows and columns in your printouts
>   by using the setRepeatingRowsAndColumns() function in the HSSFWorkbook
>   class.
>
> This function Contains 5 parameters. The first parameter is the index
>   to the sheet (0 = first sheet). The second and third parameters
>   specify the range for the columns to repreat. To stop the columns from
>   repeating pass in -1 as the start and end column. The fourth and fifth
>   parameters specify the range for the rows to repeat. To stop the
>   columns from repeating pass in -1 as the start and end rows.

```
Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("new sheet");
Sheet sheet2 = wb.createSheet("second sheet");

// Set the columns to repeat from column 0 to 2 on the first sheet
wb.setRepeatingRowsAndColumns(0,0,2,-1,-1);
// Set the the repeating rows and columns on the second sheet.
wb.setRepeatingRowsAndColumns(1,4,5,1,2);

FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xls");
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```

Comment: Hi Timbooo,I have tried but it is not repeating. i have 21 columns and 335 rows. please help me how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you. I've searched for days and found this. This solved my problem.

```
 `Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper();
    Sheet sheet1 = wb.createSheet("new sheet");

    Row row = sheet1.createRow((short) 0);
    // Create a cell and put a value in it.
    row.createCell(0).setCellValue(
            createHelper.createRichTextString("Freeze"));
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        row = sheet1.createRow((short) i);
        row
                .createCell(0)
                .setCellValue(
                        createHelper
                                .createRichTextString("This is the Moving Row"));
    }

    // Freeze just one row
    sheet1.createFreezePane(0, 1, 0, 1);`
```